# Postgresql 8.3, simple query not using index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
table1 (about 200000 records)
 number varchar(8) 

table2 (about 2000000 records)
 number varchar(8)
```

Fields 'number' in both tables have standard indexes. 
For each record in table1 there is about 10 records in table2 assigned.

I execute query:

```
explain select table1.number from table1, table2 where table1.number = table2.number;
```

Query plan shows that indexes won't be used, Seq Scans all over ;)

But if I reduce amount of records in table1 to ~2000 query plan starts showing that index will be used.

Maybe somebody can tell me why postgresql behaves in that way?

Answer (score 4):

Sequential scans are normal (and optimal) for queries with very low selectivity - that is, for queries that traverse whole tables.

When you deleted most rows from table1, it was no longer covering all possible distinct values from table2 - that's why index scan came to use.

For starters, I'd recommend trying this query:

```
select * from pg_stats where tablename in ('table1','table2');
```

That's the information that PostgreSQL uses to build a query plan.

The planner itself is quite complicated - consult the docs (mentioned by Jonathan) and sources [http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ -> src/backend/optimizer ] if you are so curious.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-examine.html) can tell you!

Here are some highlights:

> When indexes are not used, it can be
>   useful for testing to force their use.
>   There are run-time parameters that can
>   turn off various plan types (see
>   Section 18.6.1). For instance, turning
>   off sequential scans (enable_seqscan)
>   and nested-loop joins
>   (enable_nestloop), which are the most
>   basic plans, will force the system to
>   use a different plan. If the system
>   still chooses a sequential scan or
>   nested-loop join then there is
>   probably a more fundamental reason why
>   the index is not being used; for
>   example, the query condition does not
>   match the index. (What kind of query
>   can use what kind of index is
>   explained in the previous sections.)
>
> If forcing index usage does use the
>   index, then there are two
>   possibilities: Either the system is
>   right and using the index is indeed
>   not appropriate, or the cost estimates
>   of the query plans are not reflecting
>   reality. So you should time your query
>   with and without indexes. The EXPLAIN
>   ANALYZE command can be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

It could depend on the way your indexes were created. If "number" is actually a number, you should think about changing the column type to bigint. Again, not 100% sure, but I think indexing on character columns works different than on numeric-based fields...I could however be talking out of my butt.

Comment: Due to past design decisions it isn't always a number